# Undefined variable in Go

Tags: go

I'm getting an error: **undefined: req** during compilation. I understand why I'm getting the error but I'm not sure how to overcome it. This is my code:

```
switch path {
case "user.save":
    var req SaveRequest
case "user.update": 
    var req UpdateRequest
}

err := c.BindJSON(&req)
if  err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"error_code": "SERVER_ERROR", "message": "Request is not valid JSON"})
    return   
}

c.Set("req", req)
```

I'm trying to parse JSON requests and then add them to the context. I reaslise that if I define my `req` variable before the `switch` statement then this should overcome the problem but I don't know what type to declare it as initially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go is [lexically scoped using blocks](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope). This means that the declarations of `req` are only visible within their code block, the `case` block in this instance.

You need to declare `req` in the same scope, or an outer scope, from where you want to use it.

```
var req interface{}
switch path {
case "user.save":
    req = &SaveRequest{}
case "user.update": 
    req = &UpdateRequest{}
}

err := c.BindJSON(req)
```

Comment: Thanks - yes I understand scope. I'm just not sure how to best structure the code in this instance!

Comment: @tommyd456: if you want `req` to possibly be multiple types, you need to use an `interface{}` (or a more specific common interface if there is one)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about using `interface{}` in that way.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you declare it in a switch statement. There is no guarantee that either will have been defined by the time the `err := c.BindJSON(&req)` line executes. You may know, based on some outside understanding of the input, that won't happen but the compiler cannot. The variables you declare within each case statement are therefor scoped for that statement.

You just need to do a little refactoring. You could move this `err := c.BindJSON(&req)` into the case statements. You could use an interface to declare the variable more generically and deal with it's type later on ect. Do what you think reads best. Likely you've encountered this in other languages with somewhat similar type systems (same happens in C, C++, C# and Java for example).

Comment: It's not that it isn't allowed, or that neither path may have been executed, it's simply that Go is lexically scoped using blocks (doesn't have anything to do with the type system either)

Comment: @JimB good point, that was poor wording. You know what I mean, but it's technically wrong. Maybe I'll edit, maybe your comment is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `BindJSON` logic into the `switch` statement:

```
var err error
switch path {
case "user.save":
    var req SaveRequest
    err = c.BindJSON(&req)
case "user.update": 
    var req UpdateRequest
    err = c.BindJSON(&req)
}

if  err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"error_code": "SERVER_ERROR", "message": "Request is not valid JSON"})
    return   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I forgot to show that I call `req` further down too so I'm still going to be left with the same error. Could you amend your answer slightly? I've updated my code sample.